# Безопасность CRM. С чего начать и чем закончить?

Tags: .htaccess, безопасность

всегда был по ту сторону монитора и достал много важных для себя моментов с этого сообщества, но пришло время самому задать вопрос, так как устал собирать ответы из разных источников в одну кучу :D

Пишу CRM систему, ничего мегакрутого, но она заточена под определенные задачи моего интернет-магазина. И если с самой разработкой все понятно, то вот с безопасностью возникают некоторые вопросы. Нужны советы знающих людей, которые на это не только собаку съели.

CRM построена на Jquery, AJAX, PHP, HTML5, CSS3.

1. Есть ли возможность скрыть js, php файлы из инструментов разработчика, а конкретно из панели Sources и Network?
2. Как можно скрыть параметры запросов AJAX во вкладке Network (Графа Headers)?
3. Нужно ли минимизировать файлы JS для безопасности, а не для скорости обработки?
4. Файл .htaccess - насколько серьезно отнестись к скрытию расширений файлов?
5. Файл .htaccess - нужна ли такому продукту защита от SQL-иньекций и вредных запросов? Как ее лучше реализовать?
6. Стоит ли опасаться cookie и какие данные туда можно записывать, а какие не желательно из соображений безопасности?

Помимо этих вопросов, буду также услышать Ваш опыт в сфере безопасности WEB-ресурсов, может кто-то пользуется какими-то лайфхаками)

Заранее всем спасибо за помощь

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: 1. Нет / 2. Никак / 3. Минимизация лишь немного затормозит читателя, будет надо — разминимизирует обратно / 4. Расширения в вебе не имеют абсолютно никакого значения / 5. Нет никакой связи между .htaccess и SQL / 6. Куки хранятся в браузере пользователя, вот и думайте сами, что вы готовы доверить ему хранить

Comment: В основном, от sql инъекций защита это обрабатывать данные перед записью в бд, простой путь решения проблемы с sql инъекциями - использовать pdo; не стоит позволять загружать .php файлы и т.п.. Не надо забыть и о [XSS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3) атаках